# Une proposition littéraire avec mêler

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

J'ai rencontré la proposition ci-dessous:

> Il fallut que tu t'en mêlasses.

Je sais qu'**il fallut** est le passé simple du verbe falloir et **tu te mêlasses** est l’imparfait du subjonctif du verbe mêler.

Cette proposition existe dans un livre pour la préparation du Certificat Voltaire. Ce n'est pas dans un livre littéraire ni une citation d'un écrivain classique. Plus particulièrement, l'énoncé demande au lecteur de dire si la proposition est correcte ou non. Personnellement je n'ai jamais entendu l'emploi d'imparfait du subjonctif durant mon parcours dans des établissements du supérieur français. Je connais son existence, son emploi passé par des auteurs célèbres mais je trouve que son emploi a disparu voire va faire drôle.

Je me pose la question comment un temps disparu (même pour les francophones) peut faire partie d'un concours qui n'est pas, par exemple, celui de la licence ès lettres.

Une autre question : l'interpretation courante de cette proposition serait :

> Il a fallu que tu t'en mêles.

ou

> Il a fallu que tu t'en sois mêlé.

Moi je pense que ça doit être la première mais l'adaptation est-elle 100% correcte ?

Enfin, peut-on employer la structure suivante ?

> Tu n'aurais pas dû t'en mêler.

Le sens est-il toujours le même ?

Comment: "Tu n'aurais pas dû être mélangé.": Ici, tu as changé totalement le sens de la phrase. Ce n'est pas un problème relatif aux temps employés, mais aux mots et au sens totalement différent. 
"Se mêler de", c'est le sens utilisé ici avec le "en" qui cache le "de". => "Tu n'aurais pas dû t'en mêler" pour garder le sens et la structure de ta dernière question.

Comment: @Larme : Merci beaucoup ! Quelle grande bêtise j'ai faite : mélanger au lieu de se mêler de...

Comment: Avec cette petite correction, ta question devrait pouvoir se focaliser sur les temps utilisés.

Comment: @Larme Tu n'aurais pas dû t'en mêler. Je viens d'éditer le messager. Merci encore.

Comment: @jlliagre : Merci vivement pour les corrigés que tu as fait à la question.

Comment: L'hypothèse selon laquelle l'imparfait du subjonctif a disparu est inexacte. Certes il est très peu répandu mais les gens dont l'éloquence est le métier (avocats, politiques, écrvains) l'utilisent parfois.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La phrase

> *Il a fallu que tu t'en **aies** mêlé*

est en premier lieu incorrecte car l'auxiliaire choisi n'est pas le bon. Le verbe *mêler* étant employé de manière pronominale réfléchie, l'auxiliaire *être* aurait du être utilisé :

> *Il a fallu que tu t'en **sois** mêlé*.

Cette phrase reste cependant problématique car il n'y a pas d'antériorité de la subordonnée sur la principale. C'est donc bien le présent du subjonctif qui est attendu :

> *Il a fallu que tu **t'en mêles***

Le passé du subjonctif peut être utilisé dans une phrase où la subordonnée précède dans le temps la principale :

> ***J'ai regretté*** que tu t'en sois mêlé

Pour ce qui est de la pertinence de la présence de l'imparfait du subjonctif dans les questions du Certificat Voltaire, Circeus a déjà donné une bonne explication.

Answer (score 3):

*Il a fallu que tu t'en aies mêlé.* n'est pas correct. S'il est exact que de nos jours, le passé composé n'appelle plus l'imparfait du subjonctif dans la langue générale, le seul temps correct ici est le présent du subjonctif, et non le passé.

Quant à savoir pourquoi ces verbe sont si présents aux examens... eh bien il faut regarder du côté de la sociolinguistique. La maîtrise du passé simple et tout particulièrement de l'imparfait du subjonctif, formes hautement conservatrices (et irrégulières!), sont de nos jours plus un marqueur d'éducation, un [*Schibboleth*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schibboleth) qu'une notion nécessaire ou même utile à la compréhension du français. Du français contemporain, du moins: il n'y a pas si longtemps encore passé simple et passé composé avait des usages distincts, mais cette différence est de nos jour pratiquement impossible à percevoir pour la plupart des locuteurs.